# sound effect in a html5 game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to play sound effect in a game with each hit,but the sound sometimes play and others NOT !!

I'm using the next code :

```
<script>

var hitSound = new Audio();

function playEffectSound()
{
    hitSound = document.getElementById('effects'); 
    hitSound.loop =  false; 
    hitSound.currentTime = 0; 
    hitSound.play();    
}

</script>
    <audio id="effects" hidden>
    <source src="sound/mp3/effect.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="sound/wav/effect.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

any ideas ?

Comment: You have 2 `<script>` tags, forgot to close the second one?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Where is the first one closed?

Comment: It might be the file was not loaded yet when you hit it. you can try add preload attr to audio tag but it is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: @musefan, Yea, that's what I meant, that second tag should've been `</script>`

Comment: Could you please specify the target platform(s)?

Comment: @Stephen : Android browsers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to play audio

```
function playEffectSound(sound) {
    //Does the sound already exist?
    if (document.getElementById(sound) != null) {
        document.getElementById(sound).play();
        return;
    }

    //Create elements
    var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    var sourceElement = document.createElement("source");

    sourceElement.src = sound + ".mp3";
    sourceElement.type = "audio/mpeg";

    var sourceElementWave = document.createElement("source");

    sourceElementWave.src = sound + ".wav";
    sourceElementWave.type = "audio/wav";

    //Add sources to audio
    document.body.appendChild(sourceElementWave);
    document.body.appendChild(audioElement);

    audioElement.setAttribute("id", sound);
    audioElement.appendChild(sourceElement);
    audioElement.loop = false;
    audioElement.currentTime = 0;
    audioElement.play();
}
```

You can use it like this: playEffectSound("sounds/effect"); and it will either play sounds/effect.mp3 or sounds/effect.wav

Comment: Thank you for that,but it need to download the sound every time we use it ..... that is NOT good practice with games.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using audio tag try writing its script after audio tag ,If you write script before that audio tag it gives sometime problem in playing the audio,

i would recommend Write Script at the end of the page that's the standard way to write script.

http://jsfiddle.net/LyDWH/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<audio id="effects" hidden >
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
        <div onclick= "playEffectSound();">Horse Click Me..!</div>
</body>
<script>
var hitSound = new Audio();
function playEffectSound()
{
    hitSound = document.getElementById('effects'); 
    hitSound.currentTime = 0;
    hitSound.play();    
}

</script>
</html>
​
```

Comment: Thank you for that,but that is NOT helpful with games.

Comment: @Solieman- I know that its not good practice to use above code, I was just correcting above code given. Using Sprite's of Sound is good practice to follow indeed.

Answer (score -1):

try with each hit to add a new var sound and sound.play() and it will just work fine

Comment: try to add code examples, provide a reference or source, or elaborate in greater detail to provide the asker with enough detail to try out your suggestion - or at least point them in the right direction.